# partial page model on post handler is not executing | ASP.NET Core Razor Pages 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, partial-views, razor-pages

I have a partial view with a page model. In the page model class I have the OnPost handler which is not being called when the form is submitted.

**_Subscribe.cshtml**

```
@page
@model Shared._SubscribeModel

<div id="subscribe-for-updates">
    <h4>Subscribe to keep up-to-date with any changes.</h4>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="yourname@example.com" />
        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

**_Subscribe.cshtml.cs**

```
public class _SubscribeModel : PageModel
{
        public void OnGet()
        {

        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string email)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                //do something
            });

            return RedirectToPage();
        }
}
```

Now, the partial view is being rendered in the home page.

**Index.cshtml**

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Welcome";
}

<h2>Hello, Welcome to my website!</h2>

<partial name="_Subscribe" model="Model.SubscribeModel" />
```

**Index.cshtml.cs**

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public IndexModel()
        {
            SubscribeModel = new _SubscribeModel();
        }

        public _SubscribeModel SubscribeModel { get; }

        public void OnGet()
        {

        }
    }
```

I did some research and found out that the code behind partial views is not automatically executed like normal pages which means that I have to explicitly call OnPost but this seems wrong.

Am I doing something wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you not using controllers?

Comment: @JamesS MVC and Controllers is a thing of the past. Haven't you heard of Razor Pages yet? It replaced MVC as the go-to framework for server-side HTML generation when ASP.NET Core 2.0 was released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial Views should not have PageModel files. They are essentially widgets that get rendered into the calling page and become part of that. Your OnPostAsync method should be added to the PageModel class of the calling page.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying this. I decided to create a base abstract page model class which inherits from the default page model class and all of my page model classes inherit from this new base. This way I can follow the DRY principle.

Comment: @Mike Brind I'm starting with Razor Pages with EF Core. My objective would be to put the header in a partial view and in the _layout.cshtml call await Html.PartialAsync ("_ Header"), however, the a partial view "header" needs to display data coming from the database. I have already performed dependency injection of DBContext, however, I do not know what would be the best way to do it. What is your suggestion?

Comment: @Marcoscdoni Use a ViewComponent instead of a Partial: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/view-components